# Detect when text has changed AND editor has lost focus in CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to implement an autosave feature in CKEditor 5, where a save only occurs if changes were made and after the editor has lost focus.

How could I do this? The documentation has been very confusing to me.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
function onChange(el,editor) {
    editor.document.once('change',function(evt,data) {
        $(el).one('blur',function() {
            saveFunction();
            onChange(el,editor);
        });
    });
}

onChange(el,editor);
```

The problem with my solution is the blur event fires whenever CKEditor brings up a modal.

Answer (score 11):

To track the focused element of the [editor ui](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorui-EditorUI.html) you can use the [focusTracker](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorui-EditorUI.html#member-focusTracker) (available on `editor.ui.focusTracker`). It tracks various parts of the editor that are currently focused.

The [focusTracker.isFocused](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_utils_focustracker-FocusTracker.html#member-isFocused) is `true` whenever any of the editor's registered components are focused. For the [classic editor build](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html) the focused elements might be one of:

- editing area,
- toolbar,
- contextual toolbar.

```js
editor.ui.focusTracker.on( 'change:isFocused', ( evt, name, isFocused ) => {
    if ( !isFocused ) {
        // Do whatever you want with current editor data:
        console.log( editor.getData() );
    }
} );
```

Comment: This takes care of the modal problem. Thanks! I'll accept this answer when it meets all of the criteria, though. That way people who find this don't have to figure out the rest. Criteria for a save are: 1. content must have changed, and 2. editor has lost focus.

Answer (score 6):

Based on jodators answer fullfilling Adams 2nd critieria (data has changed):

```
var editor_changed = false;

editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => { editor_changed = true; });

editor.ui.focusTracker.on('change:isFocused', (evt, name, isFocused) => {
  if(!isFocused && editor_changed) {
    editor_changed = false;
    console.log(editor.getData());
  }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'm not on that project anymore, so I'm not in a position to verify this. However, if people start commenting that this works, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here a complete example based on both the answers of @Peter and @jodator. It uses the CKEditor 5 Inline Editor. As Adam Cook mentioned in his question, the documentation is not very clear.

```
<div id="textblock1" class="editor">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="textblock2" class="editor">
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus.
    </p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/17.0.0/inline/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
    var text_changed = false;

    InlineEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('.editor'), {
        })
        .then(editor => {
            window.editor = editor;

            detectTextChanges(editor);
            detectFocusOut(editor);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

    function detectFocusOut(editor) {
        editor.ui.focusTracker.on('change:isFocused', (evt, name, isFocused) => {
            if (!isFocused && text_changed) {
                text_changed = false;
                console.log(editor.getData());
            }
        });
    }

    function detectTextChanges(editor) {
        editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
            text_changed = true;
        });
    }
</script>
```