# CKEditor5, how do I write a Blur event handler in my javascript function

Tags: javascript, observable, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I have used CKEditor4 earlier and have managed writing blur event handler for it. However I am not able to understand how should I do it for CKEditor5

Here is the code I have written for CKEditor5 to capture the Blur even of it, but i do not get any alert message.

HTML

```
<div id='editor'></textarea>
```

javascript code -

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {} )
    .then( editor => {
        editor.on("blur", function(){alert("hello world");});
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    } );
```

Earlier when I used CKEditor4, my code was as follows and it worked fine for CKEditor4

HTML

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

javascript

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {});
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('blur', function () {alert("Hello World");});
```

In each of the cases above, my CKEditor loads on my page fine.

I read their documentation, but couldn't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution on stackover flow, below link -

[Detect when text has changed AND editor has lost focus in CKEditor 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321882/detect-when-text-has-changed-and-editor-has-lost-focus-in-ckeditor-5)

This is precisely what i wanted to do

heres' the solution in there

```
editor.ui.focusTracker.on( 'change:isFocused', ( evt, name, isFocused ) => {
    if ( !isFocused ) {
        // Do whatever you want with current editor data:
        console.log( editor.getData() );
    }
} );
```